# How do I achieve responsiveness?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

So this is my test site: http://www.manukarki.com

It is responsive for desktop resizing and online mobile emulations like mobiletest.me but for the real device(my moto G 1st gen) it's not working. Currently the media query for this is `@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)`. Now I also tried "max-device-width" but it changes a little but nowhere near like in screen resize and mobiletest.me test. I really don't want to use bootstrap, foundation, etc. I really want to learn from scratch.

Comment: Can you post SourceCode along with CSS

Comment: Some old browsers like ie8 didn't support media queries, therefore you should use respond.js.  Also you should/could have multiple @media clause to define css behaviour on different screen width, like desktop, tablet, mobile. Otherwise you're on the right track.

Comment: Why don't you use Bootstrap or other responsive framework. It will take things easy for you.

Comment: Well I actually want to understand the things first..

Comment: Manu, you are absolutely correct. You will become a much better develper if you understand how to code rather than how to use prebuilt framewroks which in my opinion provide far too much bloat.

Comment: Please post your code here as @Learning requested 3 hours ago. I'm not even able to reach your website, which is precisely why you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. I'm voting to close this question until it gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a viewport meta tag to the `<head>` of your page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can read more on the [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: You are very welcome, this basically forces the content to scale to the size of the devices viewport whilst respecting your CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked css file on http://www.manukarki.com/mobile.css redirects to a 404 error (and so does /code.js). Are you sure you uploaded these files correctly?

Comment: The css is actually main.css and I have yet to create javascript file which is supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), with only the CSS you can do a lot. Or go all the way, and use their Javascript as well.

But you don't seem to want to use it. Well, its your time (don't see the need to re-invent the wheel when someone else has done the hard work). Might be informative to see how they do it.